# Is there a way to select "not i" in a JS for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

In a for loop, is there a way to select all the numbers that are not equal to `i`?

Comment: Can you give some code so we can see what you are doing and can help you a bit better?

Comment: I don't currently have any code, i'm just wondering if I can do it. I would use this in styling elements that are not being iterated over

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `filter` method by filtering items that are not equal to whatever you want to skip.

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 2):

You could use continue for a for-loop

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // let's skip i == 4
    if (i == 4) {
        continue; // skips this iteration
    }

    console.log(i);
}
```